# Python - Import "PIL" could not be resolved from source, reportMissingModuleSource

Tags: python

I have this code

```
from PIL import Image
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\Filip\Desktop\turbos'
c=1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".png"):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        name='turbo'+str(c)+'.jpeg'
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        rgb_im.save(name)
        c+=1
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

*When I try to run the script in VSCode,I get this error.*

**" **Import "PIL" could not be resolved from source** "**

**I've ran the following in the terminal**

> pip uninstall PIL

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

> python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

I run these but then I still get that error when I try to run my script. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I came across this problem because I had opened vscode from my command line before I activated my virtual environment. I was able to fix the warnings from vscode by closing vscode and then reopening it from the command line after activating the virtual env.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

two things first you need to check if you are using python3(pip3 install pillow) or not.
Second you have to add it to your PATH in system variables in control panel.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to modify `PATH` for standard pip installs. Also the first point doesn't really matter, he's using `python -m pip` which will be correct if he's also launching the script like `python script.py`.

Comment: running Python 3.10.1

Comment: Did you get the same error for other modules? I believe the issue is in the VScode IDE itself (python extension) check here:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `pip install PIL`
do `pip install Pillow`

Comment: ```pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\python\lib\site-packages (9.0.1)``` I still have the same problem come up in VSCode and images don't convert

Comment: Please share the actual error that you are getting that you mentioned above. Only share the command line error that you are getting.

Comment: Okay I've restarted VSCode and that error is gone but the script runs and does nothing, I will open a new question.